# What is the fractional derivative of the function $\pi \cot (\pi x)$?

Tags: calculus, special-functions, zeta-functions, fractional-calculus

What is the fractional derivative of the function $\pi \cot (\pi x)$?

I derived the following expression:

$(\pi \cot (\pi q))^{(p)}=-\frac{\zeta'(p+1,q)+(\psi(-p)+\gamma ) \zeta (p+1,q)}{\Gamma (-p)}-\Gamma (p+1) \zeta (p+1,1-q)$

where $\psi$ is digamma,
$\zeta$ is Hurwitz zeta,
$\zeta'$ is the derivative by first argument

I want to know whether it coincides with other, traditional definitions.

This gives the formula
$(\cot (q))^{(p)}=-\frac{\zeta'(p+1,\frac q\pi)+(\psi(-p)+\gamma ) \zeta (p+1,\frac q\pi)}{\pi^{p+1}\Gamma (-p)}-\frac 1{\pi^{p+1}}\Gamma (p+1) \zeta (p+1,1-\frac q\pi)$
for fractional derivative of cotangent.

Comment: You might want to tell us which definition you used to derive the expression; else we won't know which are "other" definitions.

Comment: As @joriki alludes to, you neglected to mention what definition you're using. The Riemann-Liouville and Caputo definitions sometimes give the same results, but not always.

Comment: I did not use any particular definition, I derived the formula from completely different considerations (the derivation is only valid for cotangent).

Comment: I presume you've seen [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/20/03/)?

Comment: Oh, thanks! Very interesting!

Comment: The first formula I do not understand. What the notation it uses?

Comment: The second formula uses generalized polygamma of fractional order which itself needs definition.

Comment: The unusual notation in the first formula is explained [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Notations/3/).

Comment: Maybe this ... Write down the derivative, second derivative, third derivative,... of $\cot(x)$ to get a sequence of polynomials in $\cot(x)$.  RECOGNIZE those polynomials as some previously known orthogonal polynomials.  See if there are fractional-index versions for those.

Comment: By the way, I wonder why they on Wolfram use their complicated formula if a simpler formula in the closed form exists (on which my formula is based) $(\cot q)^{(p)}=-\frac{1}{\pi^{p+1}}\Gamma(p+1) \zeta(p+1,1-\frac {q}{\pi})-\frac{1}{\pi^{p+1}}\psi^{(p)}(\frac{q}{\pi})$

Comment: I just added the definition of Balanced Polygamma to the above formula.

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment, but too long...

Maybe this ... Write down the derivative, second derivative, third derivative,... of cot(x) to get a sequence of polynomials in cot(x).
$$\begin{align}
 \cot(x) &= \cot(x)
\\(d/dx) \cot(x) &= -1-\cot(x)^2
\\(d/dx)^2 \cot(x) &= 2 \cot(x)+2 \cot(x)^3
\\(d/dx)^3 \cot(x) &= -2-8 \cot(x)^2-6 \cot(x)^4
\\(d/dx)^4 \cot(x) &= 16 \cot(x)+40 \cot(x)^3+24 \cot(x)^5
\\(d/dx)^5 \cot(x) &= -16-136 \cot(x)^2-240 \cot(x)^4-120 \cot(x)^6
\\(d/dx)^6 \cot(x) &= 272 \cot(x)+1232 \cot(x)^3+1680 \cot(x)^5+720 \cot(x)^7
\\(d/dx)^7 \cot(x) &= -272-3968 \cot(x)^2-12096 \cot(x)^4-13440 \cot(x)^6-5040 \cot(x)^8
\end{align}$$

RECOGNIZE those polynomials as some previously known orthogonal polynomials. See if there are fractional-index versions for those.

Comment: Did you recognize it as some known polynomials?

Comment: There is the [expression](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/20/02/0003/) $$(-i)^{n+1}2^n (iu-1)\sum_{k=0}^n \left(-\frac{iu+1}{2}\right)^k k!\left[{n}\atop{k}\right]$$ Familiar? I don't quite know myself...